# Reading text into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following data stored in a .txt file:

```
one,1
two,2
three,3
......
```

I want to store the information in an array with the following structure:

```
[one,1,two,2....]
```

Here is my code so far:

```
public Shortener( String inAbbreviationsFilePath ) throws FileNotFoundException {

   Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(inAbbreviationsFilePath));
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

   while (s.hasNext()){ 
      list.add(s.next());
    }

abbreviations = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
s.close(); 
}
```

My problem is that I cant get the array to be stored so that one and 1 are in different positions. i.e at the moment the array is structured like this [one1,two2,...].

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split each line by the coma and add two parts of it to your result list:

```
public Shortener( String inAbbreviationsFilePath ) throws FileNotFoundException {

   Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(inAbbreviationsFilePath));
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

   while (s.hasNext()) {
      //HERE
      String line = s.next();
      String[] lineSplit = line.split(","); //split into two tokens
      list.add(lineSplit[0]); //word
      list.add(lineSplit[1]); //number
   }

    abbreviations = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    s.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your while loop,

```
String str;
String []st;

 while ((str=s.nextLine())!=null){
      st=str.split(","); 
      list.add(st[0]);
      list.add(st[1]); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File...
s.useDelimiter("\\s+|,");
```